# Como eu posso converter a datetime para data string?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-6

Segue o código:

```
var fullEntries = dbContext.tbl_EntryPoint
    .Join(
        dbContext.tbl_Title,
        combinedEntry => combinedEntry.entry.TID,
        title => title.TID,
        (combinedEntry, title) => new 
        {
            UID = combinedEntry.entry.OwnerUID,
            TID = combinedEntry.entry.TID,
            EID = combinedEntry.entryPoint.EID,
            Title = title.Title,
            DeadLine= combinedEntry.Date.ToShortDateString() // Aqui está o problema
        })
        .Where(fullEntry => fullEntry.UID == user.UID).ToList();
```

Como posso converter datetime para date string ?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recebo o seguinte de erro:

> `Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Então eu tirei `ToShortDateString()`, porém eu recebo dessa forma na view:

```
/Date(1491793200000)/
```

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça isso no `Select` que não terá a mensagem de ***erro***:

```
var fullEntries = dbContext.tbl_EntryPoint
    .Join(
        dbContext.tbl_Title,
        combinedEntry => combinedEntry.entry.TID,
        title => title.TID,
        (combinedEntry, title) => new 
        {
            UID = combinedEntry.entry.OwnerUID,
            TID = combinedEntry.entry.TID,
            EID = combinedEntry.entryPoint.EID,
            Title = title.Title,
            DeadLine = combinedEntry.Date
        })
        .Where(fullEntry => fullEntry.UID == user.UID)
        .ToList()
        .Select(s => new {
            s.UID,
            s.TID,
            s.EID,
            s.Title,
            DeadLine = s.DeadLine.ToShortDateString()
        })
        .ToList();
```

<sub>Referencias</sub>

- [Executando consultas com LINQ e expressões Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj128159.aspx)
- [Operações de consulta LINQ básica (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397927.aspx)
- [Método DateTime.ToShortDateString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [C# - LINQ prático e rápido](http://www.macoratti.net/11/04/c_lnq1.htm)
- [LINQ e Lambda](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/linq-e-lambda/)
- [Como escrever consultas LINQ em C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397678.aspx)